# При сохранении HTML страницы вместо неё сохраняется 404. Как это работает?

Tags: html, http

При скачивании подобной страницы https://s.onliner.by/tasks/547766 в сохраненной версии тело заказа отсутствует, выскакивает 404. Как это и можно ли обойти?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В хроме сохраняется без проблем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Часть данных там подргужается по ходу отображения, на лету. Поэтому при обычном сохранении возможно как раз чего-то не сохраняется.

Я попробовал и у меня сохраняется эта страница одним файлом (mhtml), нормально отображается потом - возможно это вам подойдет.

Answer (score 0):

Центральная часть подгружается скриптом JS, она не присутствует в момент первой загрузки самой страницы и поэтому не сохраняется. При повторном обращении скрипту видимо чего-то не хватает. В любом случае это была бы не сохранённая страница, а опять же подгруженная. В браузерах есть скриншоты всего полотна страницы, может это выход.